# Error: Could not find or load main class, build with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, compiler-errors

I'm pretty new to java programming and I'm trying to run my **.jar** file with the java command

I'm using **gradle** to build the .jar and i'm always getting

*Error: Could not find or load main class*

Here is my file architecture :

[image: File architecture]

And here is my **build.gradle** in *jcoinche_client*

```
group 'jcoinche'
version ''
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
jar {
    baseName = "jcoinche-client"
     manifest {
         attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class' : 'Main'
    }
 }
 repositories {
     mavenCentral()
 }
 dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
 }
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: I'm trying to solve that with gradle

Comment: The error meanings are always same, no matter how you try to solve

Answer (score -1):

Solve it by creating a package "client"

and by running `java -jar myjar`